# MDX: What is the difference between two these

Tags: ssas, mdx

1.`[DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key]`

2.`[DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same!

Number 1 is a short version of number 2.

The default is `.members`